# Using runtime-created delegates and objects

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, delegates

I have repeatedly struggled with this general concept so it's time to reach out. I have a LINQ query that selects a list of strings from SQL, then calls Select and supplies a static method that ingests a string and returns an object:

```
MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext();
var list = (
    from t in context.GetTable<FooTable>()
    where t.FooType = userProvidedString
    select t.SomeColumn).ToList()
        .Select(colValue => MyClass.FromString(colVal))
        .ToList();
int unique = list.Distinct(new MyClassComparer()).Count();
```

I have a handful of different "profiles" that use the same query but with different types. For example, in addition to MyClass, I have MyOtherClass that also has a FromString method that takes a string parameter, but returns an instance of itself. After I get the list back from the query, I want to call Distinct on it, providing a comparer delegate that is again determined at runtime.

The problem I always run into with this kind of thing is types at build time. I know I can create the comparer like this:

```
Type comparerType = Type.GetType(String.Format("MyNamespace.{0}Comparer", userProvidedString));
ConstructorInfo ctor = comparerType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { });
```

But when I call Invoke on the ctor, I still end up with an object that has to be cast. I'm certain this can be done, and that I am simply missing some key concept. Please deliver me an epiphany!
Thanks in advance...

Comment: _"I'm certain this can be done"_ -- you're certain what can be done? Your question is very unclear. Why are you using reflection to create the comparer in the first place? Given that you're using reflection, why do you think there would be a way for the reflection API to return a strongly-typed reference to your newly-created object? How is the reflection API supposed to know a priori what type of object you're creating? Please provide a good [mcve] that clearly illustrates what you're asking. Explain _precisely_ what it is the code does now and what you want instead.

Comment: Can't you just wrap this in a function and pass in a converter / comparer? i.e. `Func<string>` & `IConparer<T>` params

Comment: Agreeing with the above 2 comments - it seems that you just want to write your `Distinct()` method to accept an `IComparer<string>` and then have a Factory method somewhere to return an instance for an appropriate circumstance? e.g. reflection won't even be required.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity & precision. Should have just left out all the rambling about reflection. The goal is to use the same query for more than one list item type. In my example above, those types would be MyClass and MyOtherClass. Each has a FromString method that will be called on the query results. Then the unique list will be generated using the comparer that corresponds to the list item type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "constructive comments" got me headed in the right direction, and here is the solution I came up with.

```
public void Foo()
{
    string dataType = "MyClass"; // Pretend this string was specified by the user
    Type t = Type.GetType(dataType);
    Type u = Type.GetType(dataType + "Comparer"); // Implements IEqualityComparer<MyClass>
    MethodInfo method = this.GetType().GetMethod("GetUniqueItemCount", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(t, u);

    int count = (int)generic.Invoke(this, new object[] { "some data blah blah" });
}

private void GetUniqueItemCount<T, U>(string data) where T : class
                                                   where U : IEqualityComparer<T>, new()
{
    MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext();
    var list = (
        from v in context.GetTable<SomeTable>()
        select v.SomeColumn).ToList()
            .Select(cellValue => Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { cellValue }) as T)
            .ToList();
    return list.Distinct(new U()).Count();
}
```

Regrettably, I had to use Activator.CreateInstance because "new T()" can only be used with a parameterless constructor. This is not great because it's called for each item in the query result set.

All of the reflection stuff I did to create T and U and invoke the method is what I was referring to in my question post (and hoping to avoid). This solution should fully illustrate my intent here, so please chime in if you know of a cleaner approach.

Thanks again for the help!